# Cannot find main method in class Super

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run this code but its giving me the error that it cannot find main method.
how to fix this error?by defining main method in super class,we cannot run the other classes so how to fix it?

```
class Super {

int x;

void Super(int x) {
    this.x= x;
}

void display() {
    
    System.out.println("super x = " + x);
    
}

}

 class sub extends Super {
     
     int y;
     
     void sub(int x , int y) {
         Super(x);
         this.y = y;
        
         System.out.println("super x = " + x);
         System.out.println("super y = " + y);
     
     }
         
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         
         sub s1 = new sub();
         s1.sub(100, 200);
         s1.display();
        
     }
     
 }
```

Comment: Because you have `main` in a class named `sub` (not `Super`).

Comment: Code looks fine to me and you have already one `display` method and which other `display` method you are talking about ? and main method inside sub class is producing this result `super x = 100
super y = 200
super x = 100`

Comment: can u help me define it in super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file name must be `sub.java`
I guess you have your file name like `Super.java`, for that reason, when you execute the file, it throws an error. Because is searching the main method inside Super class.

Comment: class Super {
 
 int x;
 int y;
 
 void Display(int x, int y) {
  
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  
  System.out.println("super x = " + x);
  System.out.println("super y = " + y);
  
 }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
  
  Super s = new Super();
  s.Display(100,200);
 }
 
}

Comment: how about this one? i shrinked the code to one class.i think this might do it.

Comment: @sravanTG that's correct too. I tried and it worked! Just check, if you file name is `Super.java`.  and that will be work successfully.